# Why does one code work, but not the other?

Tags: javascript, string, join, split, reverse

The question I am answering: Complete the solution so that it reverses the string value passed into it.

I answered this:

```
function solution(str){
 str.split("").reverse().join("");
 return(str);
}
```

but it didnt work

Instead, this was the correct solution:

```
function solution(str){
  return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

why is it that the second solution works but not the first?

Comment: because `str.split("")` doesn't change the string to an array, it returns (gives) an array, which you are not doing anything with in your first example.

Comment: you want to assign the result back to `str` to apply the change: `str = str.split("").reverse().join("");`

Comment: `join`, `split`, etc. ( except reverse ) _returns_ new values, they do not mutate `str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable. Any method that "alters" a String is really returning the new version of the string for you to use.

In the first bit, `split`, `reverse` and `join` are all taking a string, and *returning a new string*. They don't modify `str`. You're having those functions do work, throwing away the result of the functions, then returning the original `str`.

The second version works because `join` returns a new joined String, then that new string is given to `return` to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, the variable `str` doesn't get redefined, so you end up returning the original value.  You would need to do this:

```
function solution(str){
 str = str.split("").reverse().join("");
 return(str);
}
```